# Parse application/x-httpd-php in php7 without file extention

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, php-7

Ran into this while moving some sites from a one server to another:

The .htaccess file only has this in certain directories:

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

but it does not parse url's like:

```
domain.com/dir/filenameWithoutExtension/
```

where **'filenameWithoutExtension'** contains the actual content. And should generate the page

The site is hosted on Ubuntu (Directadmin) with:

First PHP: PHP 7 php-fpm
Second PHP: PHP 5.6 suphp
Apache 2.4.33

Does anyone know how to manage this correctly?

Comment: If the URL ends in `/` Apache should try to serve the page defined in `DirectoryIndex`. What does it do when you don't have the trailing `/`?

Comment: Same thing, I've tried everything but still get the 404 - not found.

Comment: OK, what does `DirectoryIndex` define as the default page, and is there a file with that name in the directory? Also, is there a mod_rewite affecting the URL?

Comment: DirectoryIndex uses .php, maybe index.html...i'll check. The file is actually called 'index'. No mod_rewite, just the plain htaccess files with that single line. This site is built very weird, I just want to add.

Comment: @MrGlass: DirectoryIndex does all the normal stuff.

Comment: why is this voted down? Isn't it a normal question?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was voted down. It's not a common question, you've supplied the relevant info, you tried to solve it before posting, and there is no code associated for this so you shouldn't be dinged for not supplying code.